# Social Sharing with angular js

Tags: angularjs, prerender

I have developed angular js web application and hosted in IIS server. My web app is developed only by using javascript, css and html.

I am trying to implement Prerender.io in my application. I configured all the required necessary steps including

1 - Added fragment

```
<head>
  <meta name="fragment" content"!"> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{header.metaservice.metaTitle()}}" />
   <meta name="description" property="og:description" content="{{header.metaservice.metaDescription()}}" />
</head>
```

2 - Added custom header

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Prerender-Token" value="XXXX" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

3 - Defined rewrite rule

```
     <rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Seo rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                          <serverVariables>
                            <set name="HTTP_X_PRERENDER_TOKEN" value="XXX" />
                          </serverVariables>
                         <conditions>
                            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)_escaped_fragment_(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                        </conditions>
                          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://service.prerender.io/https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                        </rule> 
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

4 - Installs ARR in which i enable the proxy

However, even though I have included all the necessary steps, when I paste my link,it is showing me something like this:

[image: response]